# Python Multiprocessing, Best practice for mapping results to scientific numpy arrays

Tags: python, multiprocessing, data-science, numpy-ndarray, concurrent.futures

I don't really understand how to handle multiprocessing in Python when mapping the function results to multidimensional arrays. I provide a simple example of how I calculate it serially. The parallel computing does not work. Often, I pass a lot of arguments to a function, so this would be a very annoying way of doing it.  Is there a "better way", than creating all i,j-pairs with a reshaped meshgrid?

```
import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np

def complex_function(i,j):
    # this is a computationally intense function
    return i,j,i+j

all_i = np.arange(3)
all_j = np.arange(6)
#%% serial
solution = np.empty((len(all_i),len(all_j)),dtype=float)

for i in range(len(all_i)):
    for j in range(len(all_j)):
        solution[i,j] = complex_function(all_i[i],all_j[j])[2]

#%% parallel
solution = np.empty((len(all_i),len(all_j)),dtype=float)

I,J = np.meshgrid(all_i, all_j, sparse=False, indexing='ij')
I = I.reshape(-1)
J = J.reshape(-1)
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor: 
    for i, j, result in executor.map(complex_function, I, J):
        solution[i,j] = result
```

Okay, now I want to know wheather I can use nested functions like

```
def dummy_function(i,j):
    result = complex_function(i,j)
    return result
```

and then call dummy_function(i,j) with the executer.